# how to output symbol through wParam

Tags: windows, visual-c++

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if ( !(wParam >= 'A' && wParam <= 'Z') && !(wParam >= '0' && wParam <= '9') )
    {
        cout << (char)wParam << endl;
        cout << wParam << endl;
    }
```

I already filter out the alphanumeric input and only accept the symbols but I dunno how to output the symbols through wParam. Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by 'output the symbols'

Comment: Symbols such as -, +, [, ], \ and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply using the *wrong* Windows message.  WM_KEYDOWN reports virtual keys, not characters.  Virtual keys are translated to characters by TranslateMessage(), using the current keyboard state and active keyboard layout.  The state is important because it matters if the modifier keys are active, Shift, Alt, Control.  The layout is important because different languages map keyboard keys to different characters.  WM_KEYDOWN is only useful for short-cut key strokes.  Like F1.

Use WM_CHAR instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to cast `wParam` of `WM_KEYDOWN` to a char because it may be a virtual key code, and some of them such as arrow keys fall into a range of printable characters.

Second, it looks like you're writing a GUI application, so you wouldn't see the output of `cout`.

After you solve these two problems, use `ispunct` function.

Comment: I just use it for debugging purpose. So, what I want is just display the symbols on the console window. Can you tell me how to achieve this goal? Thanks.